# Rendering Error with EditText

Tags: android

OK. This has NOT been fun.  I have Android Studio 0.8.2 installed on two differnt Windows 7 platforms.

Yesterday on my Office PC I created a page layout that uses EditText.  Today that page will not render.  In Preview window I see: 
 Rendering Problems
 Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V 
(The page does display in the emulator)

Working on my Home PC there is no problem. 
P.S. Basic TextView is ok.  I tried TextClock and it fails too.  So what happened to my Office PC environment between yesterday and today?  Really weird.

Comment: Try rebuilding your project. Outside of that, you haven't given near enough information (maybe provide your XML layout?)

Comment: You can try with some lower version of android you used for xml preview.. i have also seen problem with TextClock but worked with some lower ver.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that that the Preview rendering is not using API 20 W. EditText is not a feature of Android wearables. Change the API to 19 and it should render fine.

Comment: That was it.  Somehow the Preview version got changed. I set it back to 4.2.2. (my target) and voila.  Thank you Orelius.